# Error response TwitterKit

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitterkit

I have one petition url request but the problem is the response data is nil , with other url request the petiton is success but with this not function! Any idea ¿?

```
let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    let statusesShowEndpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"
    //let params = ["id": "20"]
    var clientError : NSError?

    let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "GET", url: statusesShowEndpoint, parameters: nil, error: &clientError)


    client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
        if connectionError != nil {
            print("Error: \(connectionError)")
        }

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            print("json: \(json)")
        } catch let jsonError as NSError {
            print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

The error appear for console

```
"Request failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : Your credentials do not allow access to this resource. (code 220), TWTRNetworkingStatusCode=403, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json,
```

But is exclusive for this request , the other request api not appear this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code, it worked for me :

```
var userID: String = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session.userID
var client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userID)
```